# Transactions from contract adress

Tags: contract-development, transactions

I want to get all transaction associated with a contract in ethereum.
I tried to found the solution with Web3, or etherscan API ,but i didn't found anything.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this is what you are looking for:

```
const url = 'https://api-rinkeby.etherscan.io/api';
const params = {
    module: 'account',
    action: 'txlist',
    address: self.contractAddress,
    sort: 'desc',
    startblock: '2027434',  // First contract transaction
};

$.getJSON(url, params, function(resp) { ... });
```

P.S.: Do not forget to put correct API network name into url.

Comment: Is this will give mme all the transactions associated to the contract : "self.contractAddress" ? I will test it and let you know if it works. Thank you :)